can we stop the EF 6 in built transaction for every USP call?, i tried suppress transaction scope no luck
can we stop the EF 6 in built transaction for every USP call?, i tried suppress transaction scope no luck...
To stop in built transaction wrapping by Entity framework 6, so we can handle transaction from stored procedures

If you are calling a stored procedure to do a bulk update you can just run it via _context.Database.ExecuteSql() . AFAIK this does not involve any transaction wrapping as you do not call SaveChanges() in this case.  Otherwise, if you have a bulk operation you want to use a stored proc for you can use something other than EF to execute it. EF is a tool in the toolbelt. It can coexist with other tools.
